# How do I use -enableRule:AppOffline in deploy.cmd?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, iis, webdeploy

I create package:

```
msbuild myapp.csproj /T:Package /p:PublishProfile=myprofile;PackageLocation=mypackage.zip
```

Try to deploy:

```
mypackage.deploy.cmd /Y -allowUntrusted /U:user /P:pass /M:myserver -enableRule:AppOffline
```

`-enableRule:AppOffline` is totally ignored and I get no errors. I also tried with `-enableRule:AppOfflineblahblahblah` and same thing so its not even trying to validate the argument.

I want to use the script so I don't have to build a webdeploy command manually but how do I get `-enableRule:AppOffline` to work?

Edit: 
This is the msdeploy command that it generated and ran:

```
msdeploy.exe -source:package='mypackage.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="myserver",userName="****",password="****",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"C:\....\myapp\mypackage.SetParameters.xml"  -allowUntrusted -enableRule:AppOffline
```

So I was wrong, looks like it is adding the arg to webdeploy and webdeploy is the one ignoring it.

I know its being ignored because I see this error:

```
....
Error Code: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE
More Information: Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'u_extend1_x.log' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt. ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run it like this

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\r1\a\temp_web_package_4846182484981034.zip' -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='site/appname' -enableRule:AppOffline
```

I'm running the .exe not the .cmd version, which calls the .exe version as well.
The .cmd version is a command line file with predefined deployment arguments. As far as I saw in the source of the file. To add the parameter you wanted, you would have to change the generated file.

Comment: right, but the point of the cmd is so i dont have to do that, is there no way to add argument to the cmd?

Comment: I edited the answer, but as I saw in the source of the cmd file I have here, there is nothing ready to receive your addicional flag.